# How to find account owner for Android app in Google Play Developer Console?

Tags: android, google-play

This question relates to the Google Play Developer Console.

An account was shared with me over a year ago. When I select this account and click **Settings**, I see the message:

> The developer profile can only be edited by the account owner.

but when I look under **Developer Profile > Email address** it shows my own address.

Even in the section at the bottom labelled Google Wallet, it states

> ... The contact email address is my-own-email-address@gmail.com

So my question is, how do I find out which Google account is considered to be the **owner**?

If I click the button labelled **Help & Feedback > Contact Support**, it just takes me to an automated help system with no suitable options.

Comment: I've got this problem right now! Do you have any memory of what happened back in Jan 13?

Comment: I never figured it out. They might still be locked out of their own account.

Comment: check Settings -> User accounts & rights

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Arjun, but I can't see 'User accounts & rights' under Settings. All I can see is 'Account Details', 'Email preferences' and 'API access'. 'Account Details' is selected by default. Nowhere on any of those pages are the words 'User accounts & rights'.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would suggest you to search your gmail, google did send you an invitation email with owner email address in it
the title is something like "Invitation to share a Google Play Developer Console Account"

Comment: Great suggestion. I found a bunch of those invites from other projects, and it does indeed contain the owner email address. I can't find the invite for the project I care about though.... aghhhhhh!?!

Comment: I found this to be incorrect. I had precisely this problem and the developer invitations did not contain the account owner's email, they contained the email address configured in the "Email address" field of the Account Details page.

Comment: The invitation emails are from the account of the person who invited you, which could be anyone with admin permissions. It's only the owner if the owner invited you :)

Answer (score 8):

Quite some time has passed since this question was asked and answered. Nowadays, there's another/new option that can help identify the account owner:

1. Open the **Google Play Console**
2. Go to the **Users and permissions** section in the left-hand menu
3. Start clicking through the users one by one and pay attention to what is says immediately below the user's name:

[image]

For the account owner it will say - unsurprisingly - **Account owner**. For other users it will show their status (e.g. **Active**, **Invite expired** etc) and a date (when e.g. access expires, the invitation was sent).

Comment: This is the way! I forgot about which email i used to sign up my play store account, and this definitely helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you can gain access to the email account specified in the "Email address" field of the Account Details page, search that inbox for emails from "Google Billing (billing-noreply@google.com)"

I found several emails about payments through the Google Wallet Merchant Account associated with the Google Play Developer Console. Those emails contained the email address of the Play account's owner.

Answer (score 0):

As on 21st June 2023 if you go to

Users and permissions -> go to each user -> account permissions tab

If you don't see any checkboxes in front of permissions, it means that particular account is of owner.

[image: Playstore Admin Owner image]

Answer (score -1):

Click on "Users and permissions" on the left panel.
You will find the main account on the top of the list :

[image]

Comment: Sorry, that's the catch - you are able to see that page only being the owner yourself. Otherwise you'll the the "Not enough <s>gold</s> permissions, my Lord" stub

Comment: Even if you can view the "Users & permissions" page, it's not true that the first user in the list is the owner. For me, users who are yet to accept their invitation are listed first, followed by the most recently added user.